# Magento 2.3: How to attach a pdf file with new order mail?

Tags: sales-order, magento2.3, order-email, pdf, transactional-mail

I am using magento 2.3.1 I need to send a pdf with new order mail, I have already done that for magento 2.2.6 but that is not working with 2.3. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install my free open source extensions Fooman PrintOrderPdf and Fooman EmailAttachments to achieve this. Both are available via packagist so you can run

```
composer require fooman/emailattachments-m2
composer require fooman/printorderpdf-m2
bin/magento module:enable Fooman_EmailAttachments Fooman_PrintOrderPdf
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

They both work with 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

SEND EMAIL WITH ATTACHMENT IN MAGENTO 2.3 https://extait.com/blog/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-magento-2-3/